# Dashboard memory overload problem

Tags: dashboard, performance, memory

I have a client who has a dev server, and we continue to have problems.

We recently tried to install a new theme, and it's child, and it did become active, but anytime we try to access the dashboard we get this error.

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 196608 bytes)

There are only 24 active plugins, I have worked hard with the client to reduce the number of actively used plugins.

What else can I do?

I can't even install a caching plugin, without running into these memory errors.

Any suggestions?

Should I use ftp and delete the unused themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your wp-config.php you add `define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');` this will work only in back-end and do not increase memory in front-end.

If this doesn't work in your site, you can also add this `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');`